# How do I use cmake's FindJNI on Cygwin?

Tags: java, cmake, java-8, cygwin, swig

I have some SWIG code I'm trying to compile on Cygwin before I buy Visual Studio. My CMakeList.txt works fine on OSX. On Windows, I installed Cygwin's version of cmake 3.3.1, I installed the latest jdk from Oracle and ran the following CMakeLists.txt (the .lib suffix is commented because it's not helping):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(myproject)

#set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib")

find_package(Java COMPONENTS Development)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)
```

but it's choking with this output:

```
....
-- Found Java: /home/user/jdk/bin/java.exe (found version "1.8.0.71")
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.3.2/Modules/FindJNI.cmake:287 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

and this is with the following lines in my `.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/home/user/jdk"
export JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY="$JAVA_HOME/lib/jawt.lib"
export JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY="$JAVA_HOME/lib/jvm.lib"
```

which reflects a few of the things I've tried already. The reason the JDK is in my home directory is because I tried to see if the problem was the space in the original install path of `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_71` but I get the same error for both locations.

Is this something that should work?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just figured out a solution. These lines together seem to fix it:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES "lib" "")
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".dll.a" ".a" ".lib")
```

although I'm not sure why I need to set them myself.

[edit]
I bought Visual Studio and ran into a similar problem. In this case, although it found Java, it couldn't find the JNI unless I specifically selected the Win64 generator.